# Progress indicator while starting an activity via intent

Tags: android, android-intent

When I start an activity by intent that takes some time before showing up (in my case the zxing intent, see http://code.google.com/p/zxing) I want to show some progress indicator to the user until the activity is created and can get started.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method you should call `showDialog` first right at the beginning and then define the dialog in the `onCreateDialog` method (as that method will get called when you call showDialog). Once your activity has created everything you can just call `dismissDialog` Something like this:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

static final int LOADING_DIALOG = 1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
showDialog(LOADING_DIALOG);
...
...
dismissDialog(LOADING_DIALOG);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch(id)
{
case LOADING_DIALOG:
    ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loadingDialog.setMessage("Waiting to load images...");
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);

    return loadingDialog;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this approach - but it does not help - the dialog does not get shown since the activity "hangs" immediately after calling the activity intent